# @dataclass Dict Где ключ поле другого класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict, dataclass

```
@dataclass
class Object:
    name: str

@dataclass
class Point:
    x:int = 0
    y:int = 0

@dataclass
class Main:
    Points: Dict[Object.name,Point]
```

Я получаю ошибку TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got 0.

Я пробовал его предопределять как список

```
Points: Dict[Object.name,Point] = field(default_factory=dict)
```

Такая же ошибка. 
P.s. я пока не понимаю что делает field(default_factory=dict)

Comment: В аннотации типа `Dict[Object.name,Point]` должны быть указаны типы, а не поля объектов. Если ключом у вас будет выступать поле Object.name, то нужно указать его тип, а не само поле: `Dict[str,Point]`